# IOError with Python write but the directory exists

Tags: python, path, save, ioerror

I'm trying to open and write to a file which may or may not exist. I'm have Windows 7 and am using Python. I'm getting an IOError because the file was not found. Here is my code to save my file:

```
dirBool = os.path.exists(saveDir)
print dirBool
if not dirBool:
    os.mkdir(saveDir)

if saveDir == os.path.dirname(newFname):
    print 'They are the same'
else:
    print 'They are not the same'

print saveDir
print newFname
fileSpace = open(newFname, "w")
```

In another part of my code I created newFname with `os.path.join(saveDir, fname)`, with fname being what you will see below in the output. The output I get is:

```
True
They are the same
//itsofs04.itap.purdue.edu/bio_mousevision/Data/skissing/WT vs Fragile X/FXS Paper/16.02.9 4 WT 4 FX VEH vs DGX/16.02.9 CC#028849 Group1B ET#387 pre t/Pupilometry Data_1.2
//itsofs04.itap.purdue.edu/bio_mousevision/Data/skissing/WT vs Fragile X/FXS Paper/16.02.9 4 WT 4 FX VEH vs DGX/16.02.9 CC#028849 Group1B ET#387 pre t/Pupilometry Data_1.2\010 G-1-G-2-G Drifting 0.0625s Interval_2016-02-09_18-08-04_units_010 Video_pupilometry_1.2_x_y_Area.hdf5
```

I am aware that these are long names but it's required. You can see that the directory both exists, and that it is the same as the directory that the new file will be saved into.
The error I get is:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'//itsofs04.itap.purdue.edu/bio_mousevision/Data/skissing/WT vs Fragile X/FXS Paper/16.02.9 4 WT 4 FX VEH vs DGX/16.02.9 CC#028849 Group1B ET#387 pre t/Pupilometry Data_1.2\\010 G-1-G-2-G Drifting 0.0625s Interval_2016-02-09_18-08-04_units_010 Video_pupilometry_1.2_x_y_Area.hdf5'
```

Things I've tried so far:

1. Change forward slashes to backward slashes
2. Change only some of the forward slashes and/or some of the backslashes
3. Type cast newFname to str
4. Get rid of any files in the directory that come close to what newFname is called.

I can't think of anything else to do, nor why it would be throwing me that error in the first place.

Comment: I note that the full filename is in Unicode, why is that?  Are the directory names in your tests in Unicode too?

Comment: How are you getting the path names?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if the directory names are in Unicode. I pulled the filenames using Tkinter and split names up using os.path, and they don't specify what they output. Plus, I tried type casting the filename to a string and that didn't work.

Comment: If this is an network drive in Windows, you need to map it to a drive letter and use the drive letter in you path. You can't refer to network locations directly in `open()`.

Comment: this is not a solution to your problem, but if you can get rid of the spaces in the path (both directory and file name), your life will be much easier. just a best practice.

Comment: @cdarke I tested it and yes, my directory path is in Unicode.

Comment: @Munir I have the networked mapped to a drive letter, so I wonder why it's not showing up. I didn't see that before so thank you. I'm looping through os.walk from a parent directory, but I don't know why that would give me the actual network location rather than the mapped letter.

Comment: @grepe I'm not the one who makes the file or directory names, it's the grad student I work under, so I don't really have any authority over that. Thank you though.

Comment: @Munir your comment ended up helping me fix the problem. Do you want to write a reply so I can mark it as the correct one and you get credit for it? Otherwise I'll answer it myself in case other people see this post.

Comment: Sure...let me write one up in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using network drives with Windows, the drive has to be mapped to a drive letter. This can be done by right clicking My Computer > Map Network Drive. After that, use the mapped drive letter in the path to `open()`.